# Internet Explorer does not expand table after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, rendering

When I make a jquery ajax call to auto fill a dropdown on page load the dropdown control is cut off by the containing table. I understand that if set the table width to 100% it would fix this but in my case I cannot do that. This code works fine in FF. It's almost like IE won't "re-render" the page after the ajax call completes. Here's the code --

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Test 1</option>
                <option>Test 2</option>
                <option>Test 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="mySelect">              
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mySelect = $( "#mySelect" );

fillListCombo = function( json )
{
    if ( json )
    {
        mySelect.empty();
        $( json ).each( function( i, obj )
        {
            var option = $( "<option></option>" );
            option.val( obj.id );
            option.text( obj.text );
            option.appendTo( mySelect );
        } );
    }
    else
    {
        mySelect.find( 'option' ).remove().end().append( '<option value="0">(none available)</option>' ).val( '0' );
    }
}

updateListCombo = function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET", url: "http://localhost/Ajax/ListLookupPage.aspx", dataType: "json", data:
        {
            listkindid: "1", userid: "17"
        },
        timeout: 2000, success: function( opts )
        {
            fillListCombo( opts );
        },
        error: function( xhr, status )
        {
            mySelect.find( 'option' ).remove().end().append( '<option value="0">(none selected)</option>' ).val( '0' );
        }
    } );
};

updateListCombo();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish I had a public Ajax page I could provide so it could be copied and pasted in a text editor to try on your own, but I don't.

How it appears in Firefox:
[image]

How it appears in IE7/8:
[image]



Any ideas on how to force IE 7/8 to render correctly after the ajax callback is complete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but it seems that if you change an unneeded css property of the select, it will force an update.

```
$('#mySelect').css({margin: '0'}).append('<option value="0">(none available)</option>');
```

(Truncated example from yours, but principle should be the same.)

I tested this with ie7 on XP only.

Comment: Wow! Very impressive. Never thought to try that approach. Yes that definitely fixes my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Might be worth submitting a bug report to jQuery (if there isn't one already) since it only affects ie.

Comment: I added a ticket to jquery. Not sure if it's a jquery bug or if it's just an IE issue. Thanks again.